# AnimatePresence not working - trouble transitioning 2 components circularly

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am creating a login signup page in ReactJS using Framer Motion. I have created 2 components login and signup each having buttons, clicking on which the other component will render. I have used **AnimatePresence** to do exit and entry animation. but the exit animation is not working, in the exit part the component gets removed suddenly from the DOM tree without doing animation.

The component structure is like this:

- UserLoginSignUp.jsx (Parent component)

  - Login. jsx** (children component)
  - SignUp.jsx** (children component)

UserLoginSignUp.jsx

```
import { Login } from "./Login";
import { Signup } from "./Signup";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

function UserLoginSignUp({ isloged, setisloged }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="w-[40vw]">
          <AnimatePresence>
            {isloged ? (
              <Login setisloged={setisloged} />
            ) : (
              <Signup setisloged={setisloged} />
            )}
          </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { UserLoginSignUp };
```

Login.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

function Login({ setisloged }) {
  const [masterKey, setMasterKey] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = () => {
  };

  const signupHandler = () => {
    setisloged(false);
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      key="login"
      initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -100 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 1 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 200 }}
      className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-b from-[#95dab6] to-[#83b2d0]"
    >
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -100 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 200 }}
        className="bg-white p-8 rounded shadow-md w-96"
      >
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Login</h2>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter master key"
            className="w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-600  focus:border-blue-300"
            value={masterKey}
            onChange={(e) => setMasterKey(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          className="w-full bg-[#95dab6] text-white py-2 rounded hover:bg-green-400"
          onClick={handleLogin}
        >
          Login
        </button>
        <p className="mt-4 text-center">
          Don't have an account?{" "}
          <span
            className="text-green-400 cursor-pointer"
            onClick={signupHandler}
          >
            Signup
          </span>
        </p>
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export { Login };
```

SignUp.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

function Signup({ setisloged }) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [masterKey, setMasterKey] = useState("");

  const handleSignup = () => {
  };

  const loginHandler = () => {
    setisloged(true);
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
    key="signup"
    initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -100 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
    transition={{ duration: 1 }}
    exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 200 }}
      className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center  bg-gradient-to-b from-blue-600 to-purple-400">
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -100 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 200 }}
        className="bg-white p-8 rounded shadow-md w-96"
      >
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Signup</h2>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Full Name"
            className="w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300"
            value={fullName}
            onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            className="w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your Masterkey"
            className="w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300"
            value={masterKey}
            onChange={(e) => setMasterKey(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          className="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 mb-2"
          onClick={handleSignup}
        >
          Signup
        </button>
        <button
          className="w-full bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 py-2 rounded hover:bg-gray-400"
          onClick={loginHandler}
        >
          Login
        </button>
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export { Signup };
```

Answer (score 2):

AnimatePresence has a `mode` prop which is `sync` by default. changing it to `wait`  or `popLayout`  may fix your issue

```
 <div className="w-[40vw]">
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
        {isloged ? (
          <Login key="login" setisloged={setisloged} />
        ) : (
          <Signup key="signup" setisloged={setisloged} />
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried mode ="popLayout" and "wait", but it didn't work. In fact, I am having doubts regarding animatePresence, does it allow this behavior with user-made components?

I had researched on the web about this and seen a lot of tutorials but I never saw anyone doing this, all were doing the same thing changing some routes or changing inside a single component.

Comment: @KrishnaBiswal I updated the code and this approach worked for me, the problem was with those `key` props, you should pass them directly

Comment: thanks it worked, but I have another query related to the animation type. Generally, the default is set to bounce, but the animation that is being performed in this application is not bounce.